# Setting up class path in ANT build

Tags: java, ant, build

**Situation:**

I am new to making ant builds and I have managed to write one that builds the JAR and moves necessary files (Such as images and libraries) into an output folder.

**Problem:**

When I try to run the new JAR it complains that it cant find the main method (I have it specified in the manifest tag in the ANT script). I have done some research and I think its because I need to define a class-path for the compiled class' to go to but I haven't been able to get it working.

**build.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="formula_manager" default="rebuild">

  <property name="out" value="${basedir}/out/FormulaManager"/>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${out}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${out}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="build" description="Build all artifacts">
    <property name="tmp" value="${out}/temp"/>
    <mkdir dir="${tmp}"/>
    <property name="tmpJar" value="${tmp}/Formula Manager.jar"/>
    <property name="tmpFolder" value="${tmp}/FormulaManager"/>
    <jar destfile="${tmpJar}" duplicate="preserve" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
      <zipfileset dir="${out}"/>
      <zipfileset src="${basedir}/resources/pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar"/>
      <zipfileset src="${basedir}/resources/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar"/>
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
    <copy file="${tmpJar}" tofile="${tmp}/Formula Manager.jar"/>
    <mkdir dir="${out}"/>
    <copy todir="${out}">
      <fileset dir="${tmp}"/>
    </copy>
    <copy file="icon.png" todir="${out}" />
    <copy file="splash.png" todir="${out}" />
    <copy file="logo.png" todir="${out}" />
    <copy file="configuration.properties" todir="${out}" />
    <mkdir dir="${out}/resources" />
    <copydir src="resources" dest="${out}/resources" />

    <!-- Delete temporary files -->
    <delete dir="${tmp}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="rebuild" depends="clean, build"/>
</project>
```

**Output:**

```
$ java -jar "Formula Manager.jar"
Error: Could not find or load main class com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main
```

**Edit:**
I opened up the JAR in 7zip and none of the class files are there which is why the main method cant be loaded. So how do I fix this in my build.xml?

Comment: Is `com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main` the name of the class? If the class name is `com.zakscode.FormulaManager` then you need to specify `value="com.zakscode.FormulaManager"`. The class is required to have a conformant `Main` method.

Comment: Would need to see how you're running the jar file.  Since it looks like your jar file has a space in it, `Formula Manager.jar`, you would need to put quotes around it:  `java -jar "Formula Manager.jar"`

Comment: @MiserableVariable The package is "com.zakscode.FormulaManager" and the Java file is "Main.java" so I would assume "com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main" is correct

Comment: @DBug Yes there is a space and I do execute it with 'java -jar "Formula Manager.jar"'

Comment: Then @DBug's comment may be relevant. You could try renaming it FormulaManager.jar after creating it to see if that works.

Comment: Did you check the manifest in the generated jar? Does it contain the class `com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main` with a valid `Main`  method? What does `java -classpath "Formula Manager.jar" com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main` work?

Comment: @MiserableVariable When I open up the JAR the Manifest is there and it does point to the class: `Manifest-Version: 1.0 Main-Class: com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main`. I also get the same output when I run `java -classpath "Formula Manager.jar" com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main`.I am 90% sure its because I am not generating class files and referencing them.

Comment: The fact that you are not able to run it with `java -classpath` either implies that the jar file is broken. What does `jar tvf <jar-name> | findstr "com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main"` result in? (use grep instead of findstr if you are on linux etc.)

Comment: @MiserableVariable Jar isnt recognized as a command.

Comment: Then give correct path, all jdks include it

Comment: @MiserableVariable I dont think the command is relevant anymore, see edit.

Comment: It is not but it would still be good to figure it out for future use. I did ask earlier "Does it contain the class com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main with a valid Main method? ". I guess the answer is no.

Comment: My suggestion is to start simple and first create a simple jar that does not need resources, copying and renaming etc. and then take small steps at a time

Comment: @MiserableVariable I miss understood, I only looked at the manifest and it was there. I didnt look for the actual class files until later and they are missing. Do you know how to alter the build.xml to work properly?

Comment: Where are the classes? If they are from your sources you need a `javac` if they are getting copied from somewhere there has to be a `zipfileset` for them

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
Main-Class = "com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main"
```

assumes that you have the following message defined:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

in a class named `com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main` (method has to be "main", not "Main").  When defining Main-Class, you don't include the main method name, you specify the **class** that contains main, so if your main method is in FormulaManager, then you set Main-Class as follows:

```
Main-Class = "com.zakscode.FormulaManager"
```

Comment: The class name is Main and it has the method main() `class Main{ public static void main(String[] args){ ... }}` Thus it should be `Main-Class = "com.zakscode.FormulaManager.Main"`. The program runs fine, My ant script just generates a JAR I can not run so the Main method is there